# End table and start new after so many rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a dynamic table that is outputted via Cold Fusion.  The table is created fine, but one of the things I'm doing is using JavaScript to grab the table's outerHTML and assign that to a hidden elements value.  The catch is the hidden elements value needs to have tables with a max of 20 rows each, and the total from the original table can be variable.  I need to read the table's outerHTML into a Javascript variable and loop over the contents and end the table after 20 rows, then create a new table and continue adding the remaining rows to the new table.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have ColdFusion on the server outputting a table with many rows and you want to use jQuery on the client to chop that big table into many smaller tables, right? If so, here is one way to do it:

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjAU4/)

```
    var rows = $('#content tr');
    var maxTableSize = 3;
    while (rows.length) {
        var newRows = rows.splice(0, maxTableSize);
        $('<table><tbody>').append(newRows).appendTo('#output');
    }

    $('#content').remove();
```

You will need to adapt this to whatever your DOM is -- it is a quick example showing it works but you may need it to work slightly differently so consider posting a jsfiddle if this isn't what you want. Note that it is inefficient to repeatedly append to the DOM as it will trigger a lot of redraws (browser side). I wanted to keep this example simple -- you can read more about how to operate efficiently with DOM later.

The best thing would be to modify the server-side code to spit out the tables as you want them!

Comment: Thank you Cymen.  What I ended up doing is grabbing all rows inside of the tbody of the table and then looping over them, ending the table and beginning a new one when my count reached the limit I specified.  Working well.  The reason I can not have the table outputted in multiples via CF is the table that the CF query outputs is used as a dataTable and needs to be maintained as one big searchable table.  The output created from javascript function is used to add page breaks after x number of rows for when the hidden elements value is sent to the cfdocument tag to be exported as PDF.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense... I figured I would point it out just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the table is being created from query results.  That being the case, using the modulus operator on the currentrow variable from your query will get you started.